# Flask images error from API or other security measures

Tags: python, flask

How Do I prevent this in flask

```
<image src="/static/%7B%7Bprof%7D%7D" >
```

to this

```
<image src="/static/images/download.jpg" >
```

My code

```
    <image src="{{url_for('static',filename = 'images/download.jpg')}}" >
        <!--filename  = "path of your image in in static folder"-->
        <image src="{{url_for('static',filename = '{{prof}}')}}" >
```

prof is the value passed from the route

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work?

```
{{url_for('static',filename = prof)}}
```